# How does one parse nested Avro records correctly in NiFi?

Tags: avro, apache-nifi

I have incoming Avro records that roughly follow the format below. I am able to read them and convert them in existing NiFi flows. However, a recent change requires me to read from these files and parse the nested record, `employers` in this example. I read the Apache NiFi blog post, [Record-Oriented Data with NiFi](https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/)
 but was unable to figure out how to get the AvroRecordReader to parse nested records.

```
{
  "name": "recordFormatName",
  "namespace": "nifi.examples",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    { "name": "id", "type": "int" },
    { "name": "firstName", "type": "string" },
    { "name": "lastName", "type": "string" },
    { "name": "email", "type": "string" },
    { "name": "gender", "type": "string" },
    { "name": "employers",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [
            {"name": "company", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "guid", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "streetaddress", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "city", "type": "string"}
        ]}
  ]
}
```

What I hope to achieve is a flow to read the `employers` records for each `recordFormatName` record and use the PutDatabaseRecord processor to keep track of the `employers` values seen. The current plan is to insert the records to a MySQL database. As suggested in an answer below, I plan on using PartitionRecord to sort the records based on a value in the `employers` subrecord. I do not need the top level details for this particular flow.

I have tried to parse with the AvroRecordReader but cannot figure out how to specify the nested records. Is this something that can be accomplished with the AvroRecordReader alone or does preprocessing, say a JOLT Transform need to happen first?

EDIT: Added further details about database after receiving a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your target DB and what does your target table look like? PutDatabaseRecord may not be able to handle nested records unless your DB, driver, and target table support them.

Alternatively you may need to use [UpdateRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UpdateRecord/index.html) to flatten the "employers" object into fields at the top level of the record. This is a manual process (until [NIFI-4398](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4398) is implemented), but you only have 4 fields. After flattening the records, you could use [PartitionRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PartitionRecord/index.html) to get all records with a specific value for, say, employers.company. The outgoing flow files from PartitionRecord would technically constitute the distinct values for the partition field(s). I'm not sure what you're doing with the distinct values, but if you can elaborate I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Thank you for responding. These are great tips. I have updated the response to include that I am putting records into a MySQL database.

Comment: I ended up using the JOLT transform processor to flatten the JSON. From there the process was straight forward. PutDatabaseRecord worked perfectly.